# Diego Migration Issue: no space?

Tags: ibm-cloud, diego

I am trying to migrate an existing node application to Diego on IBM Bluemix, but I am getting these error messages, I have tried to migrate using the "Migrate to Diego" link in the bluemix console.

```
2017-04-24T16:20:40.27+0800 [CELL/0]     ERR Copying into the container failed: stream-in: nstar: error streaming in: exit status 2. Output: tar: ./app/client/n
ode_modules/node-modules-path/.travis.yml: Cannot open: No space left on device

2017-04-24T16:20:40.27+0800 [CELL/0]     ERR tar: ./app/client/node_modules/node-modules-path/fixtures: Cannot mkdir: No space left on device

2017-04-24T16:20:40.27+0800 [CELL/0]     ERR tar: ./app/client/node_modules/node-modules-path/fixtures: Cannot mkdir: No space left on device

2017-04-24T16:20:40.27+0800 [CELL/0]     ERR tar: ./app/client/node_modules/node-modules-path/fixtures/foo: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory

2017-04-24T16:20:40.27+0800 [CELL/0]     ERR tar: ./app/client/node_modules/node-modules-path/fixtures: Cannot mkdir: No space left on device

2017-04-24T16:20:40.27+0800 [CELL/0]     ERR tar: ./app/client/node_modules/node-modules-path/fixtures/foo/node_modules: Cannot mkdir: No such file or directory

2017-04-24T16:20:40.27+0800 [CELL/0]     ERR tar: ./app/client/node_modules/node-modules-path/fixtures: Cannot mkdir: No space left on device

2017-04-24T16:20:40.27+0800 [CELL/0]     ERR tar: ./app/client/node_modules/node-modules-path/fixtures/foo/node_modules/.gitkeep: Cannot open: No such file or d
irectory
```

Comment: Try to increase disk to deploy your application by using the `cf push -k 2G`.

Comment: Yes worked after increasing the disk space using -k argument, and looks like Diego is downloading all build packs If we do not specify one when pushing the app.